# Convolution-like operator on (probability) measures on $[0,1]$ yielding measures on $[0,1]$.

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, convolution

Is there a "correct" or "best" way to define convolution of two (Borel) probability measures on $[0,1]$ to yield another probability measure on $[0,1]$?

Recall that the convolution, $\mu * \nu$, of $\mu$ and $\nu$ is the pushforward of the product measure, $\mu \otimes \nu$, via the map $(x,y) \mapsto x+y$. So in general, $\mu * \nu$ is a measure on $[0,2]$

It seems there are at least two reasonable approaches to get a sort of convolution $\mu\#\nu$ of probability measures on $[0,1]$ that is also a probability measure on $[0,1]$.

Approach 1: Define $\mu \# \nu$ as the pushforward of $\mu \otimes \nu$ via the map $(x,y) \mapsto x+ y \mod 1$.

Approach 2: Proceed as usual, obtaining $\mu*\nu$ a probability measure on $[0,2]$, then use the bijection $x \mapsto 2x$ between $[0,1]$ and $[0,2]$ to get a measure defined only on $[0,1]$; i.e. define $\mu \# \nu ([a,b]) = \mu*\nu([2a,2b])$.

What are the advantages and disadvantages to these approaches? Is there another approach that should be considered?

Comment: I don't see that either of these approaches is "better", they're just different.  Equivalently, you're asking: Which is the better notion of addition on $[0,1]$: is it $(x,y) \mapsto x+y \bmod 1$ or $(x,y) \mapsto (x+y)/2$?  Each is useful in different situations.  And we could come up with plenty of others.

Comment: @NateEldredge Okay thanks. So there aren't, for example, any properties that regular convolution has that one of the approaches has but the other doesn't? Or are there some for each approach?

Comment: Associativity holds for $x\circ y=x+y\pmod{1}$, not for $x\circ y=\frac12(x+y)$. It would hold for every other associative composition law $\circ$ on $[0,1]$, for example $x\circ y=xy$.

Comment: @Did Thanks. I'm looking for more probabilistic advantages/disadvantages though. (Your associativity observation might well be a probabilistic one, but I don't see that it is.)